# Why is my asp.net mvc publish not working anymore?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, publish

I'm running asp.net mvc and have been since last April.  All along I have been publishing my site using the Publish feature in Visual Studio.  This week, I added some telerik scripts and the jquery 1.4 script.  For some reason, when I try to publish, it's failing on the jquery script.  All the telerik scripts loaded fine and they are in the same folder.  Any ideas?

```
------ Publish started: Project: Txxx.Sxxx.Web, Configuration: Development Any CPU ------  
Connecting to http://exx-txxx.txxxxx.com/sxxxdev/...  
Publishing folder /...  
Publishing folder App_Data...  
Publishing folder App_Data/Uploads...  
Publishing folder Content...  
Publishing folder Content/2009.3.1320...  
Publishing folder Content/Images...  
Publishing folder Content/Stylesheets...  
Publishing folder DataAccess...  
Publishing folder Helpers...  
Publishing folder Logs...  
Publishing folder Scripts...  
Unable to add 'Scripts/jquery-1.4.min.js' to the Web site.  Could not find a Web server at 'exx-txxx.txxxxx.com' on port 80. Please check to make sure that the Web server name is valid and your proxy settings are set correctly. If you are sure that everything is correct, the Web server may be temporarily out of service.  
Publishing folder Services...  
Publishing folder Views...  
Publishing folder Views/Account...  
Publishing folder Views/Activity...  
Publishing folder Views/AdHocCallReport...  
Publishing folder Views/Doa...  
Publishing folder Views/Fsr...  
Publishing folder Views/Home...  
Publishing folder Views/Report...  
Publishing folder Views/ReqShipment...  
Publishing folder Views/ServiceCall...  
Publishing folder Views/Shared...  
Publishing folder Views/Task...  
Publishing folder bin...  
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========  
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

UPDATE: I actually left the jquery file in the project but deleted all the content in it and it worked fine.  When I added the content back then the publish didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend not using the built in publish function to upload to FTP.  It occasionally has trouble with FTP sites and gives the publish failed error, however, its not a complete failure.  You only get the failed message because of the one failed file, but the rest of the site would still work.  This error has happened to me when publishing the original unmodified scripts as well as designer created files and images.

I find it much less frustrating to use the publish feature to publish a local copy or create a package (right click the web project in your solution).  Once all the published files are in my specified folder, I use some other FTP program to upload.

Comment: yep, that's what it looks like I'm going to have to do.  it looks like everything worked but nothing I had changed got uploaded for some reason.  been working fine since last april.